# Efficient surrogate function for repmat undefined in Julia 1.4

Tags: function, julia

I'm trying to use `repmat()` function in Julia 1.4.1. This is because of the known efficiency problem of `repeat()`. But when I call `repmat` I get this error:

```
julia> repmat
ERROR: UndefVarError: repmat not defined
```

So what to do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`repeat` is no longer slow for the cases where you would use `repmat` https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/26039.

Comment: So repmat is deprecated now. Thank you @Oscar Smith